How do I restore commit history for a specific file that has been renamed?
I am trying to move some files from one repository (source repository) to a new one (target repository), and I want to restore all the previous commits of those files into the target repository to credit the original authors.
I tried following this blog which succesfully worked for some files, but some files had been renamed or moved in the past in the source directory which have their previous commits depicted something like this on GitHub, basically showing the commits after the rename as default and the commits before the commits in another hyperlink. When I tried the instructions on the first blog it only restored the commits after the rename locally, while I want to restore all the commit history before and after the file rename/move.

Welcome to Stackoverflow, you need to update your question to contain in text form the code you have tried.  Linking to external code is not supported.  If you have any error messages post them as well.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
